# Servo with energy feedback

Tags: servo

I'm following the idea that it could be helpful to have a feedback of a servo. There are already servos on the [market](https://learn.adafruit.com/analog-feedback-servos) plus [self-made-tutorials](http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/tutorials/how-to-diy-128/get-position-feedback-from-a-standard-hobby-servo-3279/), but all of them provide only the actual position. What I want is the force (energy) which is currently applied to the motors because I believe this could much better be interpreted by an AI as external forces and as positioning support than the actual position does.

Are there such servos on the market and/or what's the keyword to search for them?

Comment: I don't think this is a very good forum to post this question in, you might be better getting it moved to a more generic electronics forum for a wider audience.  See if the mods will move it for you.

Comment: What you look for surely exist somewhere but not at a price you can easily afford. You’d better look for an external torque or force sensor, instead of trying to find an integrated solution.